# How to disable hover effect from a css file?

Tags: html, css

How can I disable the hover effect from a `css` file, and get a second `css file's hover attribute to work on the html element.

**Html -**

```
<p>
    <a href="" title="">demo hover</a>
</p>
```

**style.css**

```
a:hover{
    color:#000;
    background: #ccc;
    border:none;
   /*Here can be more styling*/ 
}
```

**style_new.css**

```
a:hover{
    color:green;
    background: #ccc;
    border:none;
    padding:4px;
   /*Here can be more styling*/ 
}
```

Now according to the above code I want the `style.css` hover effect to be disabled. Note that I can't change the `style.css`.

Comment: you can use `parent-child` or  `nesting` for defining the only `:hover` effect you want for any particular `DOM` element, and always put your custom `stylesheet` after the default one.

Comment: can you add a class to your markup?

Comment: @Danield nope, I can't

Answer (score 3):

You can't disable one rule, you can only override it. If you have control in the css order you could add the new rule after the previous one. *If two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins*.

```css
a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #ccc;
  border: none;
  /*Here can be more styling*/
}
a:hover {
  color: green;
  background: #ccc;
  border: none;
  padding: 4px;
  /*Here can be more styling*/
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="" title="">demo hover</a>
</p>
```

If you can't be sure for the order of rules, you have to increase specificity of new rule.

> The concept
>
> Specificity is the means by which a browser decides which CSS property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and therefore will be
>   applied. Specificity is only based on the matching rules which are
>   composed of css selectors of different sorts.
>
> How is it calculated?
>
> The specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration
>   based on the count of each selector type. In the case of specificity
>   equality, the latest declaration found in the CSS is applied to the
>   element. Specificity only applies when the same element is targeted.
>   CSS rules that directly target an element will always take precedence
>   over rules that an element inherits from an ancestor.

```css
p a:hover {
  color: green;
  background: #ccc;
  border: none;
  padding: 4px;
  /*Here can be more styling*/
}
a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #ccc;
  border: none;
  /*Here can be more styling*/
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="" title="">demo hover</a>
</p>
```

Reference: [MDN - Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) - [w3.org - Cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the css loading sequence, the last one is always effective.
Just putting the new style after the older one will be ok.

[cascading-order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order)

style.css

```
a:hover{
    color:#000;
    background: #ccc;
    border:none;
   /*Here can be more styling*/ 
}
```

style_new.css

```
a:hover{
    color:green;
    background: #ccc;
    border:none;
    padding:4px;
   /*Here can be more styling*/ 
}
```

Comment: You are right actually, but my point is how to disable only hover style only from a css file ?

Comment: Maybe you could write a single css file for the new hover attribute, and import it at last. In this way you don't need import a whole css file or changing the files loading sequence.

Comment: What order are the files loading in? If you've got the HTML of the page it would help us understand why the older rules are overwriting the newer ones.

Comment: Are there any specificity rules,like `class`,`id`?Could you paste the html codes and the styles in the browser?I think maybe another rules effects the result.

Answer (score 0):

I Would suggest instead of disabling `:hover`, set the property of the element same as `:active`, `:visited`, `:linked`.

eg:

```
a.mylink{ color:#000; text-decoration:none; cursor: default; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make the style_new.css styles to be important.
it will automatically override the style.css styles. for eg:

**Style.css**

```
    a:hover{
    color:#000;
    background: #ccc;
    border:none;
   }
```

**style_new.css**

```
 a:hover{
    color:green !important;
    background: #ccc !important;
    border:none !important;
    padding:4px !important;
}
```

Comment: It's better to avoid instructing [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) usage.

Answer (score -2):

Just make sure the `style_new.css` gets added to the HTML **after** the `style.css`. HTML and CSS are "read" top-to-bottom, which means that whatever CSS comes after the first, will overrule the first CSS.

If this doesn't work, give the `a` a `class` or `id` which you can target in your `style_new.css`.

Comment: if I go with your answer then output will be that both css styles will apply on the element which that get as you say top- to-bottom but I am asking about how to disable ?

Comment: You can't disable and it really doesn't matter if you disable or not. Only one style is added to the `a`-tag and that's the last one.

Comment: sorry, but I am not satisfy with you. If one has `animation` , `position` etc then what.

Comment: You can be not satisfied with my answer, but it's the truth. You can't disable it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for replies, but it is possible with script.

Comment: You asked if it's possible with only CSS, and it's not. If you don't like the answers you get, don't ask the question.