# Writing Bootstrap 3 Media Queries

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

I’m trying to use the Bootstrap Media Queries correctly to set the font-size when the responsive screen is in the mobile view (less than 768px).  It seems I’m not using it right, as the paragraph does not change within my container.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or give me an example of how to correctly use the media queries?

**Bootstrap Media Queries:**

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

**CSS:**

```
@media(max-width:768px){
    .aboutBlock{
        font-size: 12pt; 
    }
}

.aboutBlock{ 
    font-size: 25pt; /*I WANT THIS TO BE THE DEFAULT FOR ALL OTHER SCREENS*/
    font-family: asap-bold;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid aboutSection">
    <blockquote class="aboutBlock">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut auctor ante, eget congue nunc. Maecenas pharetra eu sem vel maximus. Duis ornare pretium porttitor.</p>
    </blockquote> 
</div> <!--container-fluid aboutSection-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it backwards. You need to have the default come *before* the media queries. This assumes a mobile-first approach. For example, from the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

So your code would actually look like:

```
.aboutBlock{ 
    font-size: 25pt; /*I WANT THIS TO BE THE DEFAULT FOR ALL OTHER SCREENS*/
    font-family: asap-bold;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
    .aboutBlock{
        font-size: 12pt; 
    }
}
```

Live jsbin example: https://jsbin.com/nunuba/

Comment: The code worked great!  Thanks so much. (note: The link you posted doesn't work).

Comment: @user5302656 it's better to update your answer and add some extra details why the change of order make rule work. This post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32114146/3834042.